# The Euler-Lagrange equation yields a constant function?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

My functional is $J[f] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x) \log f(x)\,dx$. I want to maximize it using the calculus of variations.

In order to use the Euler-Lagrange equation, I define $L(t, y, y')$ such that $J[f] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} L(t, f(x), f'(x))\,dt$:

$$L(t, y, y') = y \log y.$$

The EL equation says that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} L(t, y, y') = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} L(t, y, y').$$

(auxiliary question: why does the statement of the RHS of the EL equation use $\frac{d}{dt}$ and not $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$?)

Substituting into the EL equation, the trivial solution is $\log y + 1 = 0$, or $f(x) = \exp(-1)$. I feel like I am missing something here. What's wrong?

Comment: Regarding the use of the total time derivative: $L$ is defined to be a function with $t,y,y'$ as dependent variables. Hence $\frac{d}{dt}y = y'$ rather than $\partial_t y = 0$. (Which, in particular, would mean that all time-independent functionals would have a vanishing RHS in the Euler-Lagrange equation...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you are missing anything here.  The expression above you have is for entropy and the distribution for maximal entropy on the reals is "uniform".  In other words, the outcome of the experiment can be any value without any preference amongst them.  You will however find that there is no such "probability density" since you can't integrate a positive value over the entire reals and obtain something finite.

Comment: It's nice to hear that I got something right. What if you constrain the problem a little bit further to get a more interesting functional solution? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371678/maximize-jf-int-mathbbr-fx-log-fx-dx-over-smooth-surjections-f)

Comment: @SimonKuang - I was looking at question earlier, unfortunately don't know how to solve it.  One thing that might help is writing your surjective constraint as $\inf f = 0$, $\sup f = \alpha$.  You can say that because the functions are smooth (hence continuous).  Still, those constraints are very unusual and I am not sure how you could work them in as "lagrange multipliers".